# Node.js binding to a method from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not expert at all in Javascript and node.js
If I want to access to a method that is contained into a string, What should I do?
Is that possible?

For instance:

```
function bindJS(method, path){
   var js = require(path+".js");
}
```

and the method I'd like to get is:   js.what's_inside_method

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is method a property of `js`? Can you use `js[method]()`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is with eval which is potentially unsafe if your data comes from a non-trusted source (unless it's hard-coded into the code, it's an untrusted source). So, lots of red flags, but this should work:

```
function bindJS(method, path){
  var js = require(path+".js");
  func = eval(method);
  func();
}
```